# Taking notes vocally?

Tags: windows-7, windows, voice, note-taking

Recently my girlfriend and I were Skyping and she said the one thing she hates about taking notes in school is all the typing. That made me think--what if there was a program that allowed you to take notes without typing a word? So I thought I'd ask here. :)

**Does there exist a program that allows you to take notes vocally?** I know she could just use basic voice recording software and simply save the notes as separate audio files, but I'm wondering if there's something geared specifically to note-taking to make organization easier and more user-friendly (she isn't very tech-savvy). Ideally it would also have speech recognition to allow for searching through your notes, but I'm not going to set the bar that high. :)

She uses Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 comes with speech recognition already built-in, just open Start > Control Panels > Speech recognition, and turn it on. Accuracy is acceptable for note-taking, though you can get better quality by going through the tutorial.

Speech recognition is supported by the OS, so it works with most programs. If you are looking for a speech-enabled note-taking application, consider [OneNote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_OneNote). It indeed allows searching via speech.

Comment: Ah, didn't know OneNote had this feature! I'll wait before accepting this as the answer to see if there are any other alternatives, but this looks like what I need, thanks.

Comment: OneNote never ceases to amaze me, didn't know the part that you can search for spoken snippets as well (I use handwriting extensively, though). Also I think back in Windows Vista the Sticky Notes also supported audio – they have been streamlined quite a bit for Windows 7, though.

Comment: Tried it--works like a charm! Thanks!